# How can I write username to log in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I want to write username like extra field to production log.
How can I do it?

I have this config in config.yml:

```
services:
    monolog.formatter.logprocessor:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
        arguments:
            - "[%%datetime%%] [%%username%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%%: %%message%%\n"

monolog.processor.logprocessor:
    class: Acme\CoreBundle\Monolog\LogProcessor
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.processor, method: processRecord }
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: warning
            formatter: monolog.formatter.logprocessor
```

When I tried inject security.context into LogProcessor, I get error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]         
Circular reference detected for service "monolog.processor.logprocessor", path: "router ->  
monolog.logger.router -> monolog.processor.logprocessor -> security.context -> security.a  
uthorization_checker -> security.authentication.manager -> security.user.provider.concrete  
.chain_provider -> security.user.provider.concrete.main ->  doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> monolog.logger.doctrine".
```

Comment: Did you find out how to add these extra data?

Comment: No, I postponed it for later. :)

Comment: I made a service for this. See my answer below.

Comment: Super, you are amazing! :)

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept answer if it fits your needs : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: please accept the answer, it's exactly what you want ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the configuration

```
# Service Configuration
services:          
    monolog.formatter.html:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\HtmlFormatter

    monolog.processor.web_processor:
        class: Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.processor, method: __invoke } 

    monolog.processor.user:
        class: Company\ToolBoxBundle\Services\Monolog\ExtraProcessor
        arguments:  ["@security.token_storage"]
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.processor }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And the service code

```
namespace Company\ToolBoxBundle\Services\Monolog;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class ExtraProcessor
{
    private $tokenStorage = null;
    private $user = null;
    private $postParams = null;    

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function __invoke(array $record)
    {
        if (null !== $this->user) {
            $record['extra']['user'] = $this->user->getUserDetails();
        }

        if (null !== $this->postParams) {
            $record['extra']['postParams'] = $this->postParams;
        }

        return $record;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $postParams = $event->getRequest()->request->all();
        if(false === empty($postParams)){
            $this->postParams = serialize($postParams);
        }  

        if (null === $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
            // e.g. anonymous authentication
            return;
        }

        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: To create custom monolog processor just Create class with __invoke(array $record) method and tag it as "monolog.processor". It's not required to use tag "kernel.event_listener" - in this case it's only for get request params.

Comment: What is `getUserDetails` method?

Comment: Nothing but the text I want to write in the log. Something like the firstname lastname and ID in my case, but just return what you need.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a symfony version >= 2.4, you can have a look at [this bundle](https://github.com/M6Web/MonologExtraBundle)
 that should help you doing what you want :)